# How to pass NSDictionary to next view controller in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, nsdictionary, parameter-passing

I want to pass the NSDictionary variable to next View Controller, but it doesn't work.
How do I solve this problem? Here is my src code.

```
//...
let vc = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SearchResultView") as SearchResultViewController
vc.testId = index + 1
vc.testDict = testDataReturn(index + 1)
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
//...
func testDataReturn(rid: Int) -> NSDictionary {
    var jsonResult: NSDictionary = NSDictionary()
    let urlPath: String = "[MY TEST SERVER]/test.php"
    var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
    var request1: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)

    request1.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    var stringPost="test_id=\(rid)" // Key and Value

    let data = stringPost.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    request1.timeoutInterval = 60
    request1.HTTPBody=data
    request1.HTTPShouldHandleCookies=false

    let queue:NSOperationQueue = NSOperationQueue()

    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request1, queue: queue, completionHandler:{ (response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

        var err: NSError

        jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary

    })

    return jsonResult
}
```

testId : normally passed, but testDict : nil.
The function "testDataReturn" works well.

```
class SearchResultViewController : UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    var testId: Int = 0
    var testDict: NSDictionary = NSDictionary()
    // ...
    @IBOutlet weak var searchResultTableView: UITableView!
    // ...
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.searchResultTableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        NSLog("testDict : \(testDict)") // nil
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Have you check that `testDataReturn ()` function returns not null value?

Comment: Yes, that returns not nil, but next view has nil value.

Comment: also, that function is synchronous call

Comment: Show code that how you created `testDict` variable in `SearchResultViewController` and where you trying to get its value.

Comment: var testDict:NSDictionary = NSDictionary() ... I declared it in this way. Did I wrong init.?

Comment: Where you have written this line? In `viewDidLoad` or above this method? Edit your question and add `SearchResultViewController` relevant code.

Comment: Thanks, I'll edit my question including SearchResultViewController code

Comment: Assuming that testDataReturn(index + 1) returns a dictionary, your code should work. I tested it with a literal dictionary (vc.testDict = ["key1":"value1"]), and that dictionary was passed to vc as it should.

Comment: I'll edit my question including testDataReturn code. I want to know the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that `NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest` is an asynchronous method that executes in the background. While it executes `testDataReturn` function will continue till the end of the function. So the jsonResult will be returned as empty by the `testDataReturn` function.

Please do UI updates from inside the block `NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest`. Move the navigation code inside the block including setting of the properties.

```
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request1, queue: queue, completionHandler:{ (response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

    if error == nil
    {
        jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            let vc = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SearchResultView") as SearchResultViewController
            vc.testId = index + 1
            vc.testDict = jsonResult
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)


        })
    }
})
```

Comment: Oh, my mistake... I forgot to edit my asynchronous call. I checked that the NSDictionary variable passed normally after writing synchronous call. Thanks a lot. I solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("FirstToSecond", sender: dictionary)
```

Set dictionary for second VC in this method

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let id = segue.identifier
    if(id == "FirstToSecond"){
        var vc: AnyObject = segue.destinationViewController
        (vc as ViewController).setDictionaryMethod(sender)
    }
}
```

UPDATE:
You can use your way to pass dictionary to second VC but you should use

```
var testDic : NSDictionary?
```

instead of

```
var testDic : NSDictionary = NSDictionary()
```

Comment: I didn't use segue because it includes different next view in map area. When I tab at (141, 250) it includes value 1. However I tab at (35, 172) it includes value 13. So I didn't use segue. Instead, I used Tab Gesture Recognizer.

Comment: You can still use segues then and send the proper value. Using a segue to pass something to another VC is the cleanest method.

Comment: try to use `var testDict: NSDictionary?` instead of `var testDict: NSDictionary = NSDictionary()`

Comment: Thank you for teaching the concept "segue". I'll use segue rather than pushViewController method in most situation.